# Does Ubuntu support all video cards equally?

Tags: graphics

I've heard Nvidia cards usually have better support than ATI, but even within brands, is the support pretty even across different cards or how would I find which video cards are best supported?

Comment: This question is a hot potato.  People tend to recommend what they use and know as long as they can get it working.  There's so many cards, and even different implementations of the chipsets (as in propriety implementations in laptops and third party devices) that it's pretty hard to give definitive answers to your question.  You're more likely to get personal opinion from a very narrow viewpoint since it's very hard for any individual to test all options available.  Personally, I have Nvidia and am finding the performance and reliability very spotty.  ATI seems to be havine probs also.

Answer (score 0):

My experience is that both Nvidia and ATI are supported. Unfortunately they are not as well supported as Windows. In my ***personal experience***, I find Nvidia to be having a better drivers than ATI, on the other hand ATI has better support for open source drivers, but they often lack proper support for their latest cards (for instance the fusion platform almost took a year to get proper video accelaration support from the drivers). In the end I just tend to take an "older" card and not the latest high end ones (even on Windows the drivers are not always that good for the latest cards).